# PHP - foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Tags: php, arrays

I have this problem on this code:

```
    foreach ( $data as $index){
            //echo $index . " =>" . $skillset;
            
            $objects = [
                $index . " =>" . [$skillset].","
        ];
        }
```

The error: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

```
var_export($result)
mysqli_result::__set_state(array( 'current_field' => NULL, 'field_count' => NULL, 'lengths' => NULL, 'num_rows' => NULL, 'type' => NULL, ))
```

```
print_r($data);
Array ( [0] => ANDROID STUDIO ) Array ( [0] => C# )
```

```
print_r($skillset);
'Array','Array','Array','cs230','cs230''Java','Eclipse','Java','Eclipse','C#'
```

**What I want:**

```
$objects = [
     'ANDROID STUDIO' =>['Array','Array','Array','cs230','cs230'],
     'C#'=>['Java','Eclipse','Java','Eclipse','C#'],];
```

***What I get:***

```
ANDROID STUDIO =>'Array','Array','Array','cs230','cs230'C# =>'Java','Eclipse','Java','Eclipse','C#'
```

**MY SQL**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT S.SKILL_NAME ,
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', SK.SKILLSET_NAME, '''')) AS SKILLSET_ALL
        FROM SKILL S
        LEFT JOIN SKILLSET SK ON S.SKILL_ID = SK.SKILL_ID
        GROUP BY S.SKILL_ID, S.SKILL_NAME";
```

**My Coding**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT S.SKILL_NAME ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', SK.SKILLSET_NAME, '''')) AS SKILLSET_ALL
        FROM SKILL S
        LEFT JOIN SKILLSET SK ON S.SKILL_ID = SK.SKILL_ID
        GROUP BY S.SKILL_ID, S.SKILL_NAME";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$skillname = array();
$skillset = array();
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    

if ($checkrows > 0)
{
    
    
    foreach ($result as $results)
    {
        $skillname = $results['SKILL_NAME'];
        $skillset = $results['SKILLSET_ALL'];

        $data = [$skillname];
        //echo $data;

        foreach ( $data as $index){
            echo $index . " =>" . $skillset;
            
            $objects = [
                $index . " =>" . implode("",[$skillset]).","
        ];
        }   
    }
    
}
```

Do you know how to get the desired output?

Comment: Start by showing us the output from `var_export($result)` please. Add it to your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70653979/edit) Link

Comment: Are you trying to build an array as a string? Why not use `var_export()`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have already updated my questions...

Comment: SOrry, that was not as helpful as I expected :) Can you now do a `print_r($data);` instead of the commented `//echo $data;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly already updated print_r($data) result :DD